# How do i instruct the google's omnibar the way to do a search for my domain?

Tags: javascript, html, search

What must we do to have Google's omnibar show a custom search for our domain: [image]

Like if we go the omnibar and type s-t-a-c-k-o-v-e-r-f-l-o-w-.-c-o-m-[SPACE] the bar will come out, and typing **asd** in the box for example will take us straight to https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asd

I've noticed this behavior to be different from that of wikipedia (which takes us to http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=asd)

The behavior is also different with youtube (which takes us to http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=asd&page=&utm_source=opensearch)

Well of course not all domains have this behavior, try: g-o-d-a-d-d-y-.-c-o-m-[SPACE] *does nothing*

How do i instruct the google's omnibar the way to do a search for my domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's this line in the `<head>` of each page:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

And the file it points to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                       xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
  <Description>Search Stack Overflow: Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

It's called OpenSearch and it's a standard way of specifying how to search your website. See [the OpenSearch description specs on GitHub](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch), [an OpenSearch description format reference in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch), and [background on OpenSearch at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Preferences
2. In the "Basics" tab go down to the "Search" section.
3. Click on "Manage Search Engines" button
4. In the "Other search engines" section, you can add any domain. You just have to replace %s with the search query.

Comment: 5. Paste this on the website and have all your users do the same? I think not.